# Mockito PotentialStubbingProblem when stubbing mock for Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I have been using Mockito in this way for nearly a decade and I am at a loss what is going on here. What am I doing incorrectly here?

The actual call appears correct, but why is my stubbing shown as having empty String and nulls for parameters in the error trace?

Method under test:

```
private String harvestToken;

private String allUsersUrl;

@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

public List<HarvestUser> getActiveHarvestUsers() {
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("is_active", "true");
    String urlTemplate = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(allUsersUrl).queryParam("is_active", "true")
            .toUriString();
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    httpHeaders.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + harvestToken);
    HttpEntity<Void> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(httpHeaders);
    ResponseEntity<HarvestAllUsers> response = restTemplate.exchange(urlTemplate, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity,
            HarvestAllUsers.class, params);
    HarvestAllUsers users = response.getBody();

    if (users != null)
        return users.getUsers();
    else {
        log.warn("Harvest users not found!");
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@Mock
RestTemplate mockRestTemplate;

@InjectMocks
HarvestRestClient harvestRestClient;

@Test
void testGetActiveHarvestUsers() {
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(harvestRestClient, "harvestToken", "abc123");
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(harvestRestClient, "allUsersUrl", "http://dummy_url.com");
    when(mockRestTemplate.exchange(anyString(), eq(HttpMethod.GET), any(RequestEntity.class),
            any(Class.class), any(Map.class))).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<HarvestAllUsers>(new HarvestAllUsers(), HttpStatus.OK));
    List<HarvestUser> result =  harvestRestClient.getActiveHarvestUsers();
    assertNotNull(result);
}
```

Note: any(), anyString() and eq() are imported from org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.*
I also tried using the Mockito.* versions to same effect.

Error trace:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.PotentialStubbingProblem: 
Strict stubbing argument mismatch. Please check:
 - this invocation of 'exchange' method:
    mockRestTemplate.exchange(
    "http://dummy_url.com?is_active=true",
    GET,
    <[Content-Type:"application/json", Authorization:"Bearer abc123"]>,
    class com.demo.dto.harvest.response.HarvestAllUsers,
    {"is_active" = "true"}
);
    -> at com.demo.client.HarvestRestClient.getActiveHarvestUsers(HarvestRestClient.java:68)
 - has following stubbing(s) with different arguments:
    1. mockRestTemplate.exchange(
    "",
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
);
      -> at com.demo.client.HarvestRestClientTest.testGetActiveHarvestUsers(HarvestRestClientTest.java:52)
Typically, stubbing argument mismatch indicates user mistake when writing tests.
Mockito fails early so that you can debug potential problem easily.
```

**Update:**

I was able to get the test to pass by changing the stubbing as follows:

```
when(restTemplate.exchange(anyString(), eq(HttpMethod.GET), ArgumentMatchers.<RequestEntity<Void>>any(), any(Class.class),
                any(Map.class))).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<HarvestAllUsers>(new HarvestAllUsers(), HttpStatus.OK));
```

But I am keeping this question up because I still have no idea why the original test was failing, and this seems like an unnecessary change.